# Access Phone Features in .NET

Tags: .net

My idea is to give the details of list of SMS, Missed Calls , Received Calls in my website.

So i am planning to have the website in .net and access these phone features.

Can you please share some api links from which i can access the phone features in my website ?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your carrier

Sprint: http://developer.sprint.com/site/global/home/p_home.jsp

T-Mobile: https://code.google.com/p/tmobile-api/

Verizon: http://developer.verizon.com/content/vdc/en/verizon-tools-apis/verizon_apis.html

AT&T: http://developer.att.com/apis

Airtel: http://www.developer.airtel.in/wps/portal

I won't list them all, but I think you get the picture.

Comment: @Zech - But thing here is we have to access the SMS and Calls so have to have api for network provider also right ?

Comment: @Zech - Sry.. My understanding is you can access Phone features (Camera etc) from the above api ... but details of Call, SMS etc is not obtained from the above API right ? because it is network provider related. Its my guess..

Comment: You are talking about creating an application on the phone?

Comment: My question was to make it little simple - Can i use the above api for accessing all the features like Call Details, SMS, Camera etc in my website ?

Comment: I think that there is a language barrier here. I won't be able to help you, I am sorry.